# Josuttis Templates. 4.2 Nontype Function Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates

In this chapter Josuttis wrote a template function

```
template <typename T, int VAL> 
T addValue (T const& x) 
{ 
    return x + VAL; 
}
```

and then he used function in transform algrorithm to fill another container.

```
 std::transform (source.begin(), source.end(), // start and end of source 
 dest.begin(), // start of destination 
 addValue<int,5>); // operation
```

But after he wrote this statement :
**Note that there is a problem with this example: addValue is a function template, and function templates are 
considered to name a set of overloaded functions (even if the set has only one member). However, according to the 
current standard, sets of overloaded functions cannot be used for template parameter deduction. Thus, you have to 
cast to the exact type of the function template argument:**

```
 std::transform (source.begin(), source.end(), // start and end of source 
 dest.begin(), // start of destination 
 (int(*)(int const&)) addValue<int,5>); // operation
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Is that really quoted from the book? (the code snippets?)

Comment: yes, I copy paste it.

Comment: Well it is partly correct: `addValue` names a set of overloaded functions, so you cannot deduce a type from it. However, `addValue<int,5>` in this example only names a single function, so it is unambiguous and type deduction can take place. If there was another function like `template<typename T, int VAL> T addValue(T const& x, T const& y)` then the problem reappears for `addValue<int,5>`.

Comment: What edition of Josuttis' book?

Comment: 2002 year book. By the way could you please denote the part of standard which contains info about it.

Comment: @VahagnBabajanyan [over.over]/1 and [temp.deduct.type]/5